# jQuery-UI - Autocomplete giving me weird results

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery's autocomplete and its giving me weird results.
I am trying to get the results of either the first or last name. Right now if I start typing I only get by last name. Sometimes I get only by first name. Is there a way to do this by both first and last name?

```js
$('#userAutoComplete').autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: function(request, response) {
    response($.map(sourceValues, function(value, key) {
      var name = value.firstName + " " + value.lastName;
      name = name.toLowerCase();
      console.log(request.term);

      if (name.indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        return {
          label: value.firstName + " " + value.lastName,
          value: value.userId
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }));
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#userAutoComplete').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#specificUserId').val(ui.item.value);
  }
});
```

Here is a sample of what sourceValues is:

```
({userId: 1, firstName: "Bob" lastName: "Smith"}, {userId: 2, firstName: "Mike" lastName: "Garcia"}, {userId: 3, firstName: "Bob" lastName: "Garcia"}, {userId: 4, firstName: "Mike" lastName: "Smith"})
```

Comment: Bootstrap does not have an AutoComplete control by default. Is this a separate library you've added to your page? Looking at the code now this looks an awful lot more like [jQueryUI AutoComplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)...? In either case, please provide the content of the `sourceValues` variable so that we can create a working example of the issue

Comment: You are absolutely right, Ill get the content of sourceValues

Comment: I updated my question with the content of sourceValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `return null` - `filter()` first, `map()` afterwards.

```js
// this resolves after 2s for demo purposes
const sourceValues = mockAjaxRequest([
  {userId: 1, firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith"},
  {userId: 2, firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Garcia"},
  {userId: 3, firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Garcia"},
  {userId: 4, firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Smith"}
], 2000);

$('#userAutoComplete').autocomplete({
  minLength: 2,
  source: function (request, response) {
    const term = request.term.toLowerCase();
    sourceValues.done(values => {
      const matches = values.filter(value => {
        var name = value.firstName + " " + value.lastName;
        return name.toLowerCase().includes(term);
      }).map(value => ({
        label: value.firstName + " " + value.lastName,
        value: value.userId
      }));
      response(matches);
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#userAutoComplete').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#specificUserId').val(ui.item.value);
  }
});

function mockAjaxRequest(value, delay) {
    var req = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(() => req.resolve(value), delay);
    return req.promise();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="userAutoComplete">
<input id="specificUserId" readonly>
```

Comment: Still not working as expected

Comment: @user979331 then it's time for an [mcve].

Comment: @user979331 Don't know what you mean, this works. See extended code snippet above.

Comment: Could it be my array has 227 items and that I am getting from an ajax call?

Comment: @user979331 200-something items is not very much. If you're getting them from an Ajax call, you need to make sure you have them *before* you start filtering, but otherwise that should not be a problem. I've added demo code for how to handle Ajax data. Consult the diff of the edit to see what has changed.